# How to trigger a phone call when clicking a link in a web page on mobile phone

Tags: html, phone-call, mobile-phones, url-protocol

I need to build a web page for mobile devices. There's only one thing I still haven't figured out: how can I trigger a phone call through the click of text?

Is there a special URL I could enter like the `mailto:` tag for emails?

Device specific solution are not preferred.

I know iPhone automatically recognizes phone numbers and creates a link for this, but it would be great if this could be done for images too... and also for most mobile devices.

Answer (score 1031, accepted):

Most modern devices support the tel: scheme. So use `<a href="tel:555-555-5555">555-555-5555</a>` and you should be good to go.

If you want to use it for an image, the `<a>` tag can handle the `<img/>` placed in it just like other normal situations with : `<a href="tel:555-555-5555"><img src="path/to/phone/icon.jpg" alt="Call 555-555-5555" /></a>`

Comment: How does this downgrade for desktop? You obviously don't want this to carry the link to desktops right? Or do I have to browser sniff and kill the enclosing tag?

Comment: @3Dom [Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/62Xwc/) It launches or asks for your phone program.

Comment: @CeesTimmerman, thanks man. I tried it a while back. This seems to work pretty well now. Only hitch is that trying to copy paste the number results in clicking it, which is crappy UI, but hey, most people don't do that I'm guessing. Food for thought.

Comment: @3Dom No problem in desktop Aurora 29.0a2 (2014-02-07). You could use an image link to call (see Andrew's answer), and have the number next to it in plain text.

Comment: @3Dom in order to not show this on desktop you could (I said COULD) use user-agent sniffing *shrug*. I know I know, but FDN summarizes it like this: In summary, we recommend looking for the string “Mobi” anywhere in the User Agent to detect a mobile device. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Comment: For future reference: on OS X Yosemite and up, this will launch the Facetime app and, if the user has an iPhone, lets them actually call with their desktop/laptop.

Comment: Hello, do not forget to put the plus sign and the country code like this:
+1-555-555-5555 if you use Skype, this is a must for instant dialing.

Comment: StackOverflow you are always my saviour.

Comment: What about a 1-800 business number? ie: 1-800-555-5555

Answer (score 80):

The proper URL scheme is [number] so you would do

```html
<a href="tel:5551234567"><img src="callme.jpg" alt="Call 5551234567" /></a>
```

Answer (score 49):

Want to add an answer here for the sake of completeness.

```
<a href="tel:1234567">Call 123-4567</a>
```

Works just fine on most devices. However, on desktops this will appear as a link which does nothing when you click on it so you should consider using CSS to make it conditionally visible only on mobile devices.

Also, you should know that Skype (which is fairly popular) uses a different syntax by default (but can be parametered to use tel:).

```
<a href="callto:1234567">Call 123-4567</a>
```

However, I think in latest mobile browsers (I know for sure on Android) now the `tel` syntax should offer a popup of available applications that can be used to complete the calling action.

Comment: Does the "tel" protocol work with Skype, or only their "callto" protocol?

Answer (score 26):

**Clickable smartphone link code:**

The following link can be used to make a clickable phone link. You can copy the code below and paste it into your webpage, then edit with your phone number. This code may not work on all phones but does work for iPhone, Droid / Android, and Blackberry.

```
<a href="tel:1-847-555-5555">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

Phone number links can be used with the dashes, as shown above, or without them as well as in the following example:

```
<a href="tel:18475555555">1-847-555-5555</a>
```

It is also possible to use any text in the link as long as the phone number is set up with the "tel:18475555555" as in this example:

```
<a href="tel:18475555555">Click Here To Call Support 1-847-555-5555</a>
```

Below is a clickable telephone hyperlink you can check out. In most non-phone browsers this link will give you a "The webpage cannot be displayed" error or nothing will happen.

**NOTE:** The iPhone Safari browser will automatically detect a phone number on a page and will convert the text into a call link without using any of the code on this page.

WTAI smartphone link code:
The WTAI or "Wireless Telephony Application Interface" link code is shown below. This code is considered to be the correct mobile phone protocol and will work on smartphones like Droid, however, it may not work for Apple Safari on iPhone and the above code is recommended.

```
<a href="wtai://wp/mc;18475555555">Click Here To Call Support 1-847-555-5555</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

Essentially, use an `<a>` element with an `href` attr pointing to the phone number prefixed by `tel:`. Note that pluses can be used to specify country code, and hyphens can be included simply for human eyes.

**MDN Web Docs**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Creating_a_phone_link

> The **HTML `<a>` element** (or anchor element), along with its href attribute, creates a hyperlink to other web pages, files, locations within the same page, email addresses, or any other URL.
>
> […]
>
> Offering phone links is helpful for users viewing web documents and laptops connected to phones.
>
> `<a href="tel:+491570156">+49 157 0156</a>`

**IETF Documents**

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966

> **The `tel` URI for Telephone Numbers**
>
> The "tel" URI has the following syntax:
>
> `telephone-uri`        = `"tel:"` telephone-subscriber
>
> […]
>
> **Examples**
>
> `tel:+1-201-555-0123`: This URI points to a phone number in the United
> States.  The hyphens are included to make the number more human
> readable; they separate country, area code and subscriber number.
>
> `tel:7042;phone-context=example.com`: The URI describes a local phone
> number valid within the context "example.com".
>
> `tel:863-1234;phone-context=+1-914-555`: The URI describes a local
> phone number that is valid within a particular phone prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Just use HTML anchor tag `<a>` and start the attribute `href` with `tel:`. I suggest starting the phone number with the country code. pay attention to the following example:

```
<a href="tel:+989123456789">NO Different What it is</a>
```

For this example, the country code is `+98`.

***Hint***: It is so suitable for cellphones, I know `tel:` prefix calls `FaceTime` on macOS but on Windows I'm not sure, but I guess it caused to launch Skype.

**For more information**: you can visit [the list of URL schemes supported by browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_URI_schemes) to know all `href` values prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

At this time (2021) to work in PC or Tablet and Android (dont tested in IOS but should works) you need add **data-rel="external"** to the "a" tag, example:

```
<a href="tel:+576015000000" data-rel="external">Call Me...</a>
```