# Is possible to trigger Text Message using Html only?

Tags: html, mobile-phones

I learnt from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone) that you can trigger a phonecall using Html on modern browsers. Is it possible to trigger text messaging for mobile devices in html?

Comment: No. It is not possible in a universal way. Some devices will support `<a href="sms://1234567890">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible in a universal way.

Some devices will support the format `<a href="sms://1234567890"></a>` and some will support a default message by adding `?body=your message here` after the telephone number.