# Making http link clickable from JSON file

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I read an http link from a JSON file and bind this by using angularjs in my HTML a. The links are intended to be executed on the mobile phone. I'm creating a mobile application with Ionic framework based angularjs

JSON:

```
 [
    {
      "Name" : "ABC",
      "Address" : "ABC 11",
      "Telephone" : "+1111111",
      "Homepage": "www.google.com",
      "Mail": "test@mail.com"
    }
  ]
```

HTML:

```
 <h2>{{item.Name}}</h2>
 <h2>{{item.Address}}</h2>
 <h2><a href="tel:">{{item.Telephone}}</a></h2>
 <h2><a href="url:">{{item.Homepage}}</a></h2>
 <h2><a href="mailto:">{{item.Mail}}</a></h2>
```

The telephone number and the email address are clickable. if I click on this the telephone number will be called or the mail program will be launched. With the link of website happens nothing. How can I make the link of the Homepage from HTML clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).

Try something like this:

```
 <h2>{{item.Name}}</h2>
 <h2>{{item.Address}}</h2>
 <h2><a href="tel:">{{item.Telephone}}</a></h2>
 <h2><a ng-href="{{item.Homepage}}">{{item.Homepage}}</a></h2>
 <h2><a href="mailto:">{{item.Mail}}</a></h2>
```

Comment: I got the error from my chrome browser: 
`Cannot GET /www.google.com`

Comment: OK. It works. The form of the http link should look like:

`http://www.google.com/`
It is important to set before the `www` the protokol `http:// ` 
Thank You

Comment: No worries, happy coding! ;)

Comment: the telephone number, the email address and the web page can be clicked only on the Web browser. If I install the app on the tablet or on the phone, these links are not more clickable. How do I make these links on the devices clickable? for example, when I click on the phone number, the corresponding number should be called. or when the mail address is clicked the mail program should be executed.

Comment: Another problem is the representation of the german character like `ß, ä, ö, ü`. I embedded in my HTML the tag `<meta charset = "utf-8">` but the umlauts like `ä, ü, ö` are not displayed from my JSON file. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at HTML5 tags, they wouldn't be a tags
As for the second question I wouldn't know off the top of my head

Comment: I have encoded the JSON code with Notepad ++ with UTF-8 section and saved again. Coding problem is solved. But that the links on the device are not clickable, I could not solve so far;)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone