# Quick Call button for responsive site on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a one page responsive site and would like to know how to add a quick call button when the user view the site on their mobile phones but at the same time hide it when viewed on desktop or tablets.

Much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to that effect by picking a [specific window size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) at which the button disappears:

```
@media (min-width: 961px) {
  .button-call {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You can target the physical screen resolution by using `min-device-width` instead of `min-width`.

For the button itself, see [How to trigger a phone call when clicking a link in a web page on mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone)

Answer (score 0):

@media only screen and (min-width:600px) {

```
        .hide-on-desktop, * [aria-labelledby='hide-on-desktop'] {

            display: none;

            max-height: 0;

            overflow: hidden;
        }
```

just make sure that your button has .hide-on-desktop class...