# How to set mysql output phone number as clickable call link

Tags: php, html

I am facing the issue is mysql output result contain phone number [pnone] it should be clickable tel: link, please help me , code bellow

[image: 1]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a phone call when clicking a link in a web page on mobile phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
<a href="tel:$row['Phone']">$row["Phone"]</a>
```

Here's more info:
https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-telephone-links/

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me,

```
<td data-title="Phone" class="numeric"> <a href="tel:'.$row["Phone"].'">'.$row["Phone"].'</a></td>
```