# How do I create href for mobile dialing screen?

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>
<a href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard- 
2/awpcp-reply-to-ad/13/madame-bovary/">Contact 
Anonymous</a>
<div class="phone"><label>Phone:</label> 
7576XXXXXX</div>
<div class="location"><label>Location:</label> London, 
UK</div>

</div>
```

Price: 
    **£ 3.00**

```
<div class="fixfloat"></div>
```

I want to take the div class.phone, and make it into a button which links to mobile dialing screen.

Html and CSS options are welcome. The thing is, where do I insert the link in the html order, is it a href link, what's it's  generic url?

Each number is different, according to the person who posted the ad, and number is only visible to logged in users. Therefore, '7576XXXXXX' is just an example of one of the numbers, in a logged out view. So how do I configure this with html? Because if I use:

```
</label>7576XXXXXX
```

... and this links to dialing screen, the phone will be literally trying to dial '7576XXXXXX,' and this for every ad. Each ad will also display 7576XXXXXX as its contact number, when each ad has a different contact number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a phone call when clicking a link in a web page on mobile phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1608548/how-to-trigger-a-phone-call-when-clicking-a-link-in-a-web-page-on-mobile-phone)

Comment: Please __add__ all context and sources related to your question __directly in your question__ via [edit]. So it's easier to answer than first read all your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final version:

```
 <a href="tel:$adcontactphone"> <div class="phone">$adcontactphone</div> </a>
<a href="sms:$adcontactphone"> <div class="phone">$adcontactphone</div> </a>
```

Comment: Yes, great. Brilliant. Works.

Comment: I do have two more questions, if you wouldn't mind? The 'sms' link/element only displays the word 'Phone' and not 'SMS'. Is there a way to change this? The second question is why, in Apple mobiles, pressing the buttons for phone or sms does link to dialing screen/sms screen, but displays text '<label>call 7576XXXXXX' or something. Why is this? On android its fine, just links to screen and displays number to text or dial.

Comment: You should change the content in <lable>Phone</lable> to <label>Sms</label>, also in the <a href=...> do not use anything except the actual link . I saw in your code you have <br> and <lable> in the link which you do not need

Comment: Ok. At the moment though I don't have any labels in html I've added. It's just: <a href="sms:$adcontactphone"> <div class="phone">$adcontactphone</div> </a> if i add label it becomes: <a href="sms:$adcontactphone"> <div class="phone"><label>SMS:</label> $adcontactphone</div> </a> This has the effect of adding new word 'SMS', but keeps original word 'Phone' too. So how do get rid of original word phone from this element?

Comment: Also, in the html I've added, i haven't put br or label. That's the original html. That's more difficult to edit as original html seems encoded and spans over different files. I only have a small box to play around with, without getting to too complicated. That box now consists of....

Comment: <div id="showawpcpadpage">
<div class="awpcp-title">$ad_title</div><br/>
<div class="showawpcpadpage">
$featureimg
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">Contact Information</div>
<a href="$codecontact">Contact $adcontact_name</a><a href="tel:$adcontactphone"> <div class="phone">$adcontactphone</div> </a>
<a href="sms:$adcontactphone"> <div class="phone">$adcontactphone</div> </a>
<div class="location"><label>Location:</label> London, UK</div>

$location
$awpcpvisitwebsite
</div>
$aditemprice
$awpcpextrafields
<div class="fixfloat"></div>
$showadsense1

Comment: <div class="showawpcpadpage">
<div class="awpcp-subtitle">More Information</div>
$addetails
</div>
$showadsense2
<div class="fixfloat"></div>
<div id="displayimagethumbswrapper">
<div id="displayimagethumbs">
<ul>
$awpcpshowadotherimages
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<span class="fixfloat">$tweetbtn $sharebtn $flagad</span>
$awpcpadviews
$showadsense3
$edit_listing_link
</div>

Comment: Your answer, is the only html I've added.

Comment: Sorry but thought the comment area is not very easy to read code... let me see if we can go to chat mode

Comment: I am new in Stackoverflow..do not know how to start a chat. let me check it

Comment: Have a look for the link. It's in this page

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188928/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-krk-how-do-i-create-href-for-mobile-dialing-scree

Answer (score 1):

Most browser support it and works fine for me

```
<div class="phone"><label><a href="tel:999-999-9999">Phone:999-999-9999</a></label></div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188928/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-krk-how-do-i-create-href-for-mobile-dialing-scree).

Answer (score 0):

With HTML 5 you can wrap an A Tag around a div so:

```
<a href="http://www.yourlink.com">
<div class="phone"><label>Phone:</label> 
7576XXXXXX</div>
</a>
```

Is that you meant, maybe not.

Comment: You total pro. That's exactly what I mean. The question is, what's the link for mobile dialing screen so that, on pressing the button, your mobile will display the dialing screen with the number listed on its display, so all user has to do is press 'dial' button on dialing screen keypad?

Comment: It also has to be a generic link, and and generic number. Each number is different according to the number of the person who posted the ad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<a href="tel:99999999">Phone 999999</a>` or put a function OnClick in your DOM, your function must have a `window.open('tel:999999','_system')`